# parsing using sscanf not working

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

Need to get the value parsing using sscanf .. used as bellow but not getting the result..

String : abc_2_4
I need to get 4

### My program

```
  char sentence []="abc_1_2";
  char str [20];
  int i,j;

  sscanf (sentence,"%s_%d_%d",str,&i,&j);
  printf ("%s  %d %d\n",str,i,j);
```

### Output

abc_1_2  32768 134520820

My doubt can we use a non-white space char '_' in the string to be parsed by sscanf .

Please give me some idea.

Comment: Note: Good practice to check the result of `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sscanf()` won't "look ahead" when parsing the `%s` to know that it should end with the underscore, that's not what the `%s` conversion specifier means.

You need to use `%[^_]` to capture all characters except underscore.

Answer (score 2):

`sscanf` expects the %s tokens to be `whitespace` delimited . But here you have no space between `abc` and `_` . So it will count `_` also.

So in your case `str` will contain whole string `abc_1_2` and `i` and `j` have garbage values.

To neglect `_` you can try something like this.

```
  sscanf (sentence,"%[^_]_%d_%d",str,&i,&j);
```